# Unable to modify file in mounted volume in Kubernertes deployment as nonroot user

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to make a deployment with a simple activeMq docker. Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG UID=1001
ARG GID=1100

RUN addgroup -g $GID mygroup && \
    adduser -D --shell /bin/bash --uid $UID -G mygroup --disabled-password myuser

COPY apache-activemq-5.16.6 /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6
#COPY  --chown=1001:1001 apache-activemq-5.16.6 /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6
#COPY  --chown=1001:1001 startApp.sh /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/bin/

ENV ACTIVEMQ_TMP=/tmp

USER ${UID}

WORKDIR /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/bin

RUN pwd

EXPOSE 8161 61616

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/bin/activemq","console"]
```

and deployment is -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s-active-mq-dep
  labels:
    app: k8s-active-mq-dep
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-active-mq-dep
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-active-mq-dep
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: k8s-active-mq-dep
        image: otnqhi9c1vkceu04ehigxgp9.azurecr.io/broker-image:v3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
          - name: WRITEFILE
            value: "true"
          - name: ACTIVEMQ_TMP
            value: "/tmp"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8161
          - containerPort: 61616
        securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1001
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsGroup: 1100
        
        volumeMounts:
          - name: log-writing-folder
            mountPath: /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/data
          - name: log-writing-folder-tmp
            mountPath: /tmp

      volumes:
        - name: log-writing-folder
          csi:
            driver: file.csi.azure.com
            volumeAttributes:
              shareName: "mnt"
              secretName: seq-secret
              mountOptions: "dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,cache=strict,actimeo=30" 

        - name: log-writing-folder-tmp
          csi:
            driver: file.csi.azure.com
            volumeAttributes:
              shareName: "tmp"
              secretName: seq-secret
              mountOptions: "dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,cache=strict,actimeo=30"
```

I can access the homepage with a virtualservice, but cannot go other page like 'manage active mq broker'. in the logs I get this

```
...
 WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/data only has 10207 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 10207 mb
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/
 INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/api/jolokia/
 WARN | /admin/
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to set last modified date for file [/tmp/jetty-127_0_0_1-8161-admin-_admin-any-897734904540550475/jsp/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to set last modified date for file [/tmp/jetty-127_0_0_1-8161-admin-_admin-any-897734904540550475/jsp/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to set last modified date for file [/tmp/jetty-127_0_0_1-8161-admin-_admin-any-897734904540550475/jsp/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:377)
....
```

I am not able to set the mount option correctly ? How to set the mount option ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to set the mount option correctly ? How to set the mount option ?

You can make use of below deployment yml code:-

**My init-container.yml:-**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s-active-mq-dep
  labels:
    app: k8s-active-mq-dep
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-active-mq-dep
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-active-mq-dep
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: take-data-dir-ownership
        image: alpine:3
        command:
        - chown
        - -R
        - 472:472
        - "/tmp"
      - name: take-data-dir-ownership-2
        image: alpine:3
        command:
        - chown
        - -R
        - 472:472
        - "/opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/data"
      containers:
      - name: k8s-active-mq-dep
        image: otnqhi9c1vkceu04ehigxgp9.azurecr.io/broker-image:v3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
          - name: WRITEFILE
            value: "true"
          - name: ACTIVEMQ_TMP
            value: "/tmp"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8161
          - containerPort: 61616
        securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1001
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsGroup: 1100
        
        volumeMounts:
          - name: log-writing-folder
            mountPath: /opt/apache-activemq-5.16.6/data
          - name: log-writing-folder-tmp
            mountPath: /tmp

      volumes:
        - name: log-writing-folder
          csi:
            driver: file.csi.azure.com
            volumeAttributes:
              shareName: "mnt"
              secretName: seq-secret
              mountOptions: "dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,cache=strict,actimeo=30" 

        - name: log-writing-folder-tmp
          csi:
            driver: file.csi.azure.com
            volumeAttributes:
              shareName: "tmp"
              secretName: seq-secret
              mountOptions: "dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,cache=strict,actimeo=30"
```

**Output:-**

Applied the above yml file in my kubernetes:-

```bash
kubectl apply -f init-containers.yaml
```

[image]

**Workload got created:-**

[image]